# How can I fix this html code to not display sensitive information to the user?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, html, asp.net

I am creating a html form to capture applicants' inputs and then send a POST request to an api with the data. I do not know how to go about hiding three specific values from something like 'View Page Source' or console.log(). I need to store the values securely and still be able to use them in the HTML form.

I know I will probably have to rewrite my solution but I do not know the best way to go about this. Is there a way to store the values of the api keys in a database?

Here are the three values in question:

```
<body>
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" onsubmit="beforeSubmit(); return false;">

        <div class="aspNetHidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="merchantID" id="merchantID" />
            <input type="hidden" name="login" id="login" />
            <input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" />
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var merID = "1234567";//need to store these values somewhere else!!!!!!!
            var log = "API123";
            var pass = "1234567";
            //even if these values are moved they would be viewable by something like console.log(obj)
            document.getElementById("merchantID").value = merID;
            document.getElementById("login").value = log;
            document.getElementById("password").value = pass;
        </script>
```

And here is where I make the API call:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    beforeSubmit = function () {
        //======================================================================================================
        $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function () {
                if (o[this.name]) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };
        //======================================================================================================
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("POST", "https://someurl.com/enroll.svc/JSON/CreateMerchant", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        var obj = JSON.stringify($('#form1').serializeObject());
        console.log(obj);//security concern! all someone would have to do is cntrl+shift+j when the form is submitted
                         //this log command would display the entire JSON object including the merchant ID, Login and Password
        xhttp.send(obj);
    }   //=====================================================================================================
</script>
```

I am very new to this. The code does what it is supposed to aside from sensitive information easily being viewed by inspecting the page source. Any suggestions of for a better/more secure way would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot hide anything which can be viewable in the source. You can minify JS, which makes it harder to read, but you cannot hide it.

Comment: Also you seem to be using jQuery, so please use $.post or $.ajax instead of xmlhttp

Comment: Okay. Would I need to use something like asp .net core? Do you know of a good starting point for how to achieve this functionality properly? I just need it to be a web page.

Comment: To truly hide them from the client-side you will need to have the server handle the request and only hand the result back to an ajax call, the server can keep this sensitive information in it's config file (or better still as environment variables) mitigating this risk... ASP.net frameworks are fine but that means this page becomes a web app and it's a bit too much work to be throwing in to one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its shouldn't be too hard put your api in a php variable then insert your variable into your database table.

Then use select to take it out when you need it also php is not readable from view source.

If you don't know how to input and select from databases there are plenty of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a horrid mix of unnecessary serialisation you are not using and a weird event handling of beforesubmit.

This is how a generic jQuery ajax looks like

```js
$(function() { // page load
  $("#form1").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the submit
    $.post("https://someurl.com/enroll.svc/JSON/CreateMerchant", // url
      $(this).serialize(), // serialising the form
      function(result) {
        console.log(result); // do something with the result of the submission
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1">
  <div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="merchantID" id="merchantID" />
    <input type="hidden" name="login" id="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" />
  </div>
</form>
```